# Is there a systematic method for simplifying or reducing macro_rules?

Tags: rust, macros, metaprogramming

I want to emulate capture rules in cpp using a macro as a learning exercise, and I realized that rustfmt doesn't always play nice. I also am wondering if there is a way of simplifying or using particular techniques to reduce the complexity of macro rules. Like if there is a standard form for macro_rules.

Here is the macro in question:

```
macro_rules! capture {
    ([$($tail:tt)*] $expression:expr) => (
        {
            capture![$($tail)*];
            $expression
        }
    );
    [mut $value:ident, $($tail:tt)*] => {
        let mut $value = $value.clone();
        capture![$($tail)*];
    };
    [mut $value:ident] => {
        let mut $value = $value.clone();
    };

    [$value:ident, $($tail:tt)*] => {
        let $value = $value.clone();
        capture![$($tail)*];
    };
    [$value:ident] => {
        let $value = $value.clone();
    };

    [$name:tt = $value:expr, $($tail:tt)*] => {
        let $name = $value;
        capture![$($tail)*];
    };
    [$name:tt = $value:expr] => {
        let $name = $value;
    };

    [mut $name:tt = $value:expr, $($tail:tt)*] => {
        let mut $name = $value;
        capture![$($tail)*];
    };
    [mut $name:tt = $value:expr] => {
        let mut $name = $value;
    };
}
```

which may be used like the following:

```
#[test]
fn test_capture() {
    let a = String::from("hello");
    let b = String::from("world");

    let x = capture!([mut a, b, c = 42] move || a.clone() + &b + &c.to_string() );

    let _ = a;
    let _ = b;

    let _ = x();
    let _ = x();

    println!("{:?}", x());
}
```

I tried to reduce the macro rules by creating a comma separated list, similar to the `vec` macro, but the vec macro takes a homogenous list of expr I believe which makes the problem simplier. In contrast my problem wants to be able to accept different kinds of token patterns, but it causes a lot of boilerplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is avoid duplicating your tailed and non-tailed rules via a zero-or-one repetition: matching on `$(...)?` and expanding with `$(...)*`. That at least reduces your rules into only the major forms of your DSL:

```
macro_rules! capture {
    ([$($tail:tt)*] $expression:expr) => (
        {
            capture![$($tail)*];
            $expression
        }
    );
    [mut $value:ident $(, $($tail:tt)*)?] => {
        let mut $value = $value.clone();
        $(capture![$($tail)*];)*
    };
    [$value:ident $(, $($tail:tt)*)?] => {
        let $value = $value.clone();
        $(capture![$($tail)*];)*
    };
    [$name:tt = $value:expr $(, $($tail:tt)*)?] => {
        let $name = $value;
        $(capture![$($tail)*];)*
    };
    [mut $name:tt = $value:expr $(, $($tail:tt)*)?] => {
        let mut $name = $value;
        $(capture![$($tail)*];)*
    };
}
```

As for something more "systematic"... eh no, not really. Not that I can think of. You can check out the [`tracing::event`](https://docs.rs/tracing/latest/tracing/macro.event.html) macro to see it has many very similar arms as well.

Comment: Thanks this definitely helps, because each block is now expressing one semantic. What I meant by systematic is that for something like lexing rules, there is a normalized form. Same with boolean logic. I was wondering if those kinds of normalization rules could apply to macros as well. Like a set of reduction rules. I guess not.

Comment: @JinyoungChoi You can see a few different "patterns" used in macros from [The Little Book of Rust Macros](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/README.html) (chapter 4). That will probably help a little bit to know what kind of syntax and parsing is possible with `macro_rules!`.